# Fastest way to check ancestors using XPath and libxml2

Tags: c, xml, performance, xpath, libxml2

I'm working on a little reading app that processes HTML documents using `libxml2`. While processing an HTML tree, I check every `text()` node for its ancestors to choose a proper style. For headers I'm using the following of query to see whether a node is header or not:

```
boolean(ancestor::*[
self::h1 or 
self::h2 or 
self::h3 or 
self::h4 or 
self::h5 or 
self::h6])
```

With a 5 MB book, it takes 1.1 seconds to pass. Together with two additional queries for emphasis and code styles (with larger set of node names), it adds up to 4.4 seconds.

According to Apple's Instruments, the bottleneck line is:

```
xmlXPathObject *object = xmlXPathNodeEval(node, query, context);
```

I cache `context` to speed things up. Is there anything else I could do to make it faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your XPath expression is optimal for libxml2. But it seems that you don't precompile your XPath query. If you compile the query using `xmlXPathCompile` once at the beginning of your program and evaluate it with `xmlXPathCompiledEval`, you should see a significant speedup.

On top of that, you can get a small speedup by removing the `boolean` function from your query and calling `xmlXPathCompiledEvalToBoolean` directly.